# image shows empty object while dispatching action in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm working with yup and formik validation forms in react, the problem is I want to upload the Image that i'm selecting from 'input' as a type='file', but when I'm dispatching action it shows empty.

here is the given code and response.

[image]

[image]

until this point everything is OK, and the image is shown by the "FileReader()".

***Full Code Files...***

***AddPromotion.js***

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import * as Yup from 'yup'
import classNames from 'classnames'
import Spinner from '../common/Spinner'
import Skeleton from 'react-loading-skeleton'

import { useFormik } from 'formik'
import { isObjEmpty } from '@utils'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { useHistory, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import { LazyLoadImage } from 'react-lazy-load-image-component'
import { handleAddPromotion, resetAddPromotion } from '../../redux/actions/promotion/AddPromotionAction'
import { Button, Card, CardBody, CardHeader, CardTitle, Col, Form, FormFeedback, FormGroup, Input, Label, Row } from 'reactstrap'


const PreviewImage = ({ file }) => {
  const [preview, setPreview] = useState(null)
  const { currentSkin } = useSelector(state => state.skin)
  const reader = new FileReader()
  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  }
  reader.onloadend = () => {
   setPreview(reader.result)
  }

  return (
    <Col sm={12} md={6} lg={4} className='d-flex mt-1'>
      {preview ? (
        <LazyLoadImage
          alt='icon1'
          src={preview}
          width='80px'
          height='80px'
          style={{ borderRadius: '10px' }}
          placeholder={<Skeleton baseColor={currentSkin === 'light' ? '#ebebeb' : '#bebebe'} width={80} height={80} />}
        />
      ) : (
        <Skeleton
          style={{ visibility: 'hidden' }}
          baseColor={currentSkin === 'light' ? '#ebebeb' : '#bebebe'}
          width={80}
          height={80}
        />
      )}
    </Col>
  )
}

function AddPromotion() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const history = useHistory()
  const { id } = useParams()
  const formData = new FormData()

  const [imageData, setImageData] = useState('')
  const SUPPORTED_FORMATS = ['image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/svg', 'image/webp']
  const { inProcess, addPromotionData, error } = useSelector(state => state.addPromotion)

  const addPromotionSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    screenId: Yup.string().required('Screen ID is a required field!').max(30, 'Screen ID must be less than 30 characters!'),
    image: Yup.mixed()
      .required('Image is a required field!')
      .test('fileSize', 'File size is too large!', value => {
        if (value) {
          return value.size < 1 * 1024 * 1024
        }
        return true
      })
      .test('fileFormat', 'File format is not supported!', value => {
        if (value) {
          return SUPPORTED_FORMATS.includes(value.type)
        }
        return true
      }),
    frequency: Yup.number()
      .required('Frequency is a required field!')
      .min(1, 'Frequency must be greater than 0!')
      .max(100, 'Frequency must be less than 100!'),
    show: Yup.object().shape({
      value: Yup.number()
        .required('Value is a required field!')
        .min(1, 'Value must be greater than 0!')
        .max(60, 'Value must be less than 60!'),
      interval: Yup.string()
        .required('Interval is a required field!')
        .matches(/^(seconds|minutes|hours)$/, 'Interval must be either seconds, minutes, hours!')
    }),
    delay: Yup.object().shape({
      value: Yup.number()
        .required('Value is a required field!')
        .min(1, 'Value must be greater than 0!')
        .max(60, 'Value must be less than 60!'),

      interval: Yup.string()
        .required('Interval is a required field!')
        .matches(/^(seconds|minutes|hours)$/, 'Interval must be either seconds, minutes, hours!')
    }),
    expiryTime: Yup.date().required('Expiry Time is a required field!'),
    title: Yup.string().max(80, 'Title must be less than 80 characters!'),
    body: Yup.string().max(250, 'Body must be less than 250 characters!'),
    url: Yup.string().url('URL must be a valid URL!')
  })

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      screenId: '',
      frequency: '',
      show: {
        value: '',
        interval: ''
      },
      delay: {
        value: '',
        interval: ''
      },
      expiryTime: '',
      title: '',
      body: '',
      url: '',
      image: ''
    },
    enableReinitialize: true,
    validationSchema: addPromotionSchema,
    onSubmit: values => {
      if (isObjEmpty(formik.errors)) {
        const data = {
          screenId: values.screenId,
          frequency: values.frequency,
          show: {
            value: values.show?.value,
            interval: values.show?.interval
          },
          delay: {
            value: values.delay?.value,
            interval: values.delay?.interval
          },
          expiryTime: values.expiryTime,
          title: values.title,
          body: values.body,
          url: values.url
        }
        dispatch(handleAddPromotion(id, JSON.stringify(data), imageData))
      }
    }
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (addPromotionData?.success) {
      history.push('/list-promotions')
    }
  }, [addPromotionData?.success])

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      dispatch(resetAddPromotion())
    }
  }, [addPromotionData?.success])

  const onImageChange = e => {
    if (e.target && e.target.files[0]) {
      formData.append('image', e.currentTarget.files[0])
      formik.setFieldValue('image', e.currentTarget.files[0])
    }
    for (const value of formData.values()) {
      setImageData(value)
    }
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Card>
        <CardHeader>
          <CardTitle>Add Promotion</CardTitle>
        </CardHeader>

        {/* Loading */}
        {inProcess ? (
          <Spinner />
        ) : (
          <CardBody>
            <Form method='post' encType='multipart/form-data' onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
              <Row>
                <Col sm={12} md={4} lg={6} className='mb-3 mb-md-0'>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label for='screenId' className='form-label'>
                      Screen ID
                    </Label>
                    <Input
                      autoFocus
                      type='text'
                      name='screenId'
                      id='screenId'
                      placeholder='Enter Screen ID'
                      {...formik.getFieldProps('screenId')}
                      className={classNames({ 'is-invalid': formik.touched.screenId && formik.errors.screenId })}
                    />
                    {formik.touched.screenId && formik.errors.screenId ? (
                      <FormFeedback>{formik.errors.screenId}</FormFeedback>
                    ) : null}
                  </FormGroup>

                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label for='frequency' className='form-label'>
                      Frequency
                    </Label>
                    <Input
                      type='number'
                      name='frequency'
                      id='frequency'
                      placeholder='frequency'
                      {...formik.getFieldProps('frequency')}
                      className={classNames({ 'is-invalid': formik.touched.frequency && formik.errors.frequency })}
                    />
                    {formik.touched.frequency && formik.errors.frequency ? (
                      <FormFeedback>{formik.errors.frequency}</FormFeedback>
                    ) : null}
                  </FormGroup>

                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label for='title' className='form-label'>
                      Title
                    </Label>
                    <Input
                      type='text'
                      name='title'
                      id='title'
                      placeholder='title'
                      {...formik.getFieldProps('title')}
                      className={classNames({ 'is-invalid': formik.touched.title && formik.errors.title })}
                    />
                    {formik.touched.title && formik.errors.title ? <FormFeedback>{formik.errors.title}</FormFeedback> : null}
                  </FormGroup>

                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label for='url' className='form-label'>
                      URl
                    </Label>
                    <Input
                      type='url'
                      name='url'
                      id='url'
                      placeholder='url'
                      {...formik.getFieldProps('url')}
                      className={classNames({ 'is-invalid': formik.touched.url && formik.errors.url })}
                    />
                    {formik.touched.url && formik.errors.url ? <FormFeedback>{formik.errors.url}</FormFeedback> : null}
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>

                <Col sm={12} md={8} lg={6} className='mb-3 mb-md-0'>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label for='show.value' className='form-label'>
                      Frequency
                    </Label>
                    <Col className='d-flex'>
                      <div className='d-flex flex-column flex-grow-1'>
                        <Input
                          type='number'
                          name='show.value'
                          id='show.value'
                          placeholder='Show Value'
                          style={{ marginRight: '7px' }}
                          {...formik.getFieldProps('show.value')}
                          className={classNames({ 'is-invalid': formik.touched.show?.value && formik.errors.show?.value })}
                        />
                        {formik.touched.show?.value && formik.errors.show?.value ? (
                          <FormFeedback>{formik.errors.show?.value}</FormFeedback>
                        ) : null}
                      </div>
                      <div className='d-flex flex-column ' style={{ minWidth: '120px', maxWidth: '250px' }}>
                        <Input
                          type='select'
                          name='show.interval'
                          id='show.interval'
                          placeholder='Interval'
                          style={{ marginLeft: '7px' }}
                          {...formik.getFieldProps('show.interval')}
                          className={classNames({ 'is-invalid': formik.touched.show?.interval && formik.errors.show?.interval })}
                        >
                          <option value=''>Choose...</option>
                          <option value='seconds'>Seconds</option>
                          <option value='minutes'>Minutes</option>
                          <option value='hours'>Hours</option>
                        </Input>
                        {formik.touched.show?.interval && formik.errors.show?.interval ? (
                          <FormFeedback>{formik.errors.show?.interval}</FormFeedback>
                        ) : null}
                      </div>
                    </Col>
                  </FormGroup>

                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label for='show.value' className='form-label'>
                      Delay
                    </Label>
                    <Col className='d-flex'>
                      <div className='d-flex flex-column flex-grow-1'>
                        <Input
                          type='number'
                          name='delay.value'
                          id='delay.value'
                          placeholder='Delay Value'
                          style={{ marginRight: '7px' }}
                          {...formik.getFieldProps('delay.value')}
                          className={classNames({ 'is-invalid': formik.touched.delay?.value && formik.errors.delay?.value })}
                        />
                        {formik.touched.delay?.value && formik.errors.delay?.value ? (
                          <FormFeedback>{formik.errors.delay?.value}</FormFeedback>
                        ) : null}
                      </div>
                      <div className='d-flex flex-column' style={{ minWidth: '120px', maxWidth: '250px' }}>
                        <Input
                          type='select'
                          name='delay.interval'
                          id='delay.interval'
                          placeholder='Interval'
                          style={{ marginLeft: '7px' }}
                          {...formik.getFieldProps('delay.interval')}
                          className={classNames({
                            'is-invalid': formik.touched.delay?.interval && formik.errors.delay?.interval
                          })}
                        >
                          <option value=''>Choose...</option>
                          <option value='seconds'>Seconds</option>
                          <option value='minutes'>Minutes</option>
                          <option value='hours'>Hours</option>
                        </Input>
                        {formik.touched.delay?.interval && formik.errors.delay?.interval ? (
                          <FormFeedback>{formik.errors.delay?.interval}</FormFeedback>
                        ) : null}
                      </div>
                    </Col>
                  </FormGroup>

                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label for='expiryTime' className='form-label'>
                      Expiry Time
                    </Label>
                    <Input
                      type='date'
                      name='expiryTime'
                      id='expiryTime'
                      placeholder='expiryTime'
                      {...formik.getFieldProps('expiryTime')}
                      className={classNames({ 'is-invalid': formik.touched.expiryTime && formik.errors.expiryTime })}
                    />
                    {formik.touched.expiryTime && formik.errors.expiryTime ? (
                      <FormFeedback>{formik.errors.expiryTime}</FormFeedback>
                    ) : null}
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>

                <FormGroup>
                  <Label for='body' className='form-label'>
                    Body
                  </Label>
                  <Input
                    type='textarea'
                    name='body'
                    id='body'
                    placeholder='body'
                    {...formik.getFieldProps('body')}
                    className={classNames({ 'is-invalid': formik.touched.body && formik.errors.body })}
                  />
                  {formik.touched.body && formik.errors.body ? <FormFeedback>{formik.errors.body}</FormFeedback> : null}
                </FormGroup>
              </Row>

              <FormGroup>
                <Row className='d-flex align-items-center'>
                  <Col sm={12} md={8} lg={6} className='mt-1'>
                    <Label for='image' className='form-label'>
                      Image
                    </Label>
                    <Input
                      name='image'
                      id='image'
                      type='file'
                      // onChange={event => formik.setFieldValue('image', event.target.files[0])}
                      onChange={onImageChange}
                      className={classNames({ 'is-invalid': formik.touched.image && formik.errors.image })}
                    />
                    {formik.touched.image && formik.errors.image ? <FormFeedback>{formik.errors.image}</FormFeedback> : null}
                  </Col>
                  <PreviewImage file={formik.values.image} />
                </Row>
              </FormGroup>

              {addPromotionData?.success && <p className='text-success'>{addPromotionData?.msg}</p>}
              {error && (
                <p className='text-danger'>
                  {error.errors && error.errors.length ? `${error.errors[0].param} ${error.errors[0].msg}` : error.msg}
                </p>
              )}

              <Button type='submit' color='primary'>
                Add Promotion
              </Button>
            </Form>
          </CardBody>
        )}
      </Card>
    </Fragment>
  )
}

export default AddPromotion
```

***AddPromotionAction.js***

```
import useJwt from '@src/auth/jwt/useJwt'
import {
  ADD_PROMOTION_FAILED,
  ADD_PROMOTION_INITIATED,
  ADD_PROMOTION_SUCCESS,
  RESET_PROMOTION_STATES
} from '../ActionTypes/promotion'

export const resetAddPromotion = () => ({ type: RESET_PROMOTION_STATES })
export const addPromotionInitiated = () => ({ type: ADD_PROMOTION_INITIATED })
export const addPromotionSucceeded = data => ({ type: ADD_PROMOTION_SUCCESS, payload: data })
export const addPromotionFailed = error => ({ type: ADD_PROMOTION_FAILED, payload: error })

export const handleAddPromotion = (_id, data, imageData) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      dispatch(addPromotionInitiated())
      console.log('promotion initiated in actions')
      const response = await useJwt.addPromotion(_id, data, imageData)
      console.log('add promotion response in actions.', response)
      if (response) {
        dispatch(addPromotionSucceeded(response.data))
        console.log('promotion succeeded in actions')
      }
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.response) {
        dispatch(addPromotionFailed(err.response.data))
        console.log('promotion failed in actions', err.response.data)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

***jwtService***

```
addPromotion(_id, data, imageData) {
    
    console.log(`addPromotion in jwt Service: appId:`, _id, 'Data:', data, 'image:', imageData)

    return axios.post(`${this.jwtConfig.addPromotionEndpoint}${_id}`, data, imageData)
  }
```

[image]

Comment: How are you handling this on backend ?

Comment: I'm not working on backend, backend has been build by someone else, I think the problem is with the 'enctype', as I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I think the problem is in the backend, the backend only accepts some specified types of file like `jpg` or `png`

Comment: i have checked it with all these formats,

" const SUPPORTED_FORMATS = ['image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/svg', 'image/webp']"

Comment: try the API with postman

Comment: response in Post Man => "{
    "success": true,
    "msg": "Promotion added successfully"
}"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243278/discussion-between-haris-ahmad-and-dharmik-patel).

Answer (score 0):

this kind of problem appear because we are sending an image to the backend, so it has to be sent as a multipart form data, and for that we will have to use 'formData()' object. and then append each key-value pair.

```
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      label: '',
      adFormat: '',
      screenId: '',
      frequency: '',
      delay: {
        value: '',
        interval: ''
      },
      expiryTime: '',
      title: '',
      body: '',
      url: '',
      btnText: '',
      image: ''
    },
    enableReinitialize: true,
    validationSchema: addPromotionSchema,
    onSubmit: values => {
      if (isObjEmpty(formik.errors)) {
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('label', values.label)
        formData.append('adFormat', values.adFormat)
        formData.append('screenIds', values.screenId.split(','))
        formData.append('frequency', values.frequency)
        formData.append('title', values.title)
        formData.append('body', values.body)
        formData.append('url', values.url)
        formData.append('btnText', values.btnText)
        formData.append('image', values.image)
        formData.append('frequency', values.frequency)
        formData.append('delay[value]', values.delay?.value)
        formData.append('delay[interval]', values.delay?.interval)
        formData.append('expiryTime', values.expiryTime)

        dispatch(handleAddPromotion(id, formData))
      }
    }
  })
```